# Customize UItableView to populate data from Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I'm getting data from web service and populating the data in UITable View in objective-c.Data is coming correctly in table view . I followed this blog, http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm. 
I want to customize the cell according to my requirement. I want an image view on left side and some labels beside it. But when i custom the cell and add image view and label beside it the data does not come to the specific location and image does not load. Can anyone help me how can i do this. Want to customize according to the screen shot.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: show your code?

Comment: He probably just added stuff to interface without connecting them :)

Comment: check screen shots. Yes yet i haven't connected them but how should i do that.I want the custom pattern same when data loads in it and data should go to their own position. @emotality

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text =` you keep overriding this with different values. So it will just end up with the last assignment. You would need to add labels and drag them to this class to add them as properties, then you can do `self.dealerNameLabel.text =` and `self.locationLabel.text =` etc.

Comment: let me try it. @emotality

Comment: It is not showing me property and giving error that property not found in uitableviewcell. I have made their outlets in the class but its showing error. @emotality

Comment: Those variable names were just as an example, I don't know what our variable names are. Search youtube on how to link properties in Xcode, because this is not the place, the answer would have to look like a wiki page. Watch tutorials how its done if you don't know how to. :)

Comment: i know to link them but when i link a label as a property it, shows error that property cannot be use to repeat content in uitableview. @emotality

Comment: help me bro. @emotality